# this is a code for left rotation of an array....how to optimize it further as it's giving TLE error

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int main() {

    int n,d,i=0,temp;
    cin>>n>>d;          
    int a[1000000];           
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){         
        cin>>a[i];
          } 

  while(d--){             

        temp=a[0];

        for(i=1;i<n;i++){
            a[i-1]=a[i];}
        a[n-1]=temp;
        } 

      for(i=0;i<n;i++){

        cout<<a[i]<<" ";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

how to optimize it further as it's giving TLE error. the input file is very large obviously.

Comment: Do One rotation "big" instead of `d` small rotation.

Comment: Before you reinvent the wheel use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) so you only have the number of elements that you need and then use [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

Comment: Please mention the upper bounds of `a` and `d`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Seems likely that HackerEarth is presenting this challenge as a largely pointless exercise in doing precisely that: reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Rotate by the full amount `d` in a single loop (note that the result is a different array `b`):

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       b[(i+n-d) % n]=a[i];
   }
   ```
2. Don't touch the array at all but transform the index when accessing it, for example:

   ```
   cout << a[(i+n-d) % n] << " ";
   ```

The second version requires extra calculation to be done whenever accessing an array element but it should be faster if you don't need to access all array elements after each rotate operation.

3. There is also a way to do the rotation in-place by using a helper function that reverses a range of the array. It's a bit odd but might be the best solution. For convenience I have used a `std::vector` instead of an array here:

   ```
   void ReverseVector( std::vector<int>& a, int from, int to ) {
       for (auto i = 0; i < (to - from) / 2; i++) {
           auto tmp = a[from + i];
           a[from + i] = a[to - i];
           a[to-i] = tmp;
       } 
   }

   void RotateVector( std::vector<int>& a, int distance ) {
       distance = (distance + a.size()) % a.size();
       ReverseVector( a, 0, a.size() - 1 );
       ReverseVector( a, 0, distance - 1 );
       ReverseVector( a, distance, a.size() - 1 );
   }
   ```

Comment: it worked only after i put the rotated elements in a new array...
   b[(i+n-d) % n]=a[i];

thanks a lot anyway...you were helpful.

Comment: @PIYUSHSHEKHAR: You're right of course. I have edited my answer and added a 3rd version that does the rotation in-place.